# Yarn upgrade - Is the new version saved?

Tags: yarnpkg

Say I have a `package.json` file in an existing project. In there I have `"some-package": "^1.0-01",`, however I know that the latest version is `1.0-02`

So I do `yarn upgrade`. However, `package.json` is not update, and still references the  `-01` version. The `yarn.lock` file however shows this:

```
some-package@^1.0-01:
  version "1.0-02"
```

Is this expected behavior? When someone else does the `yarn` command, which version will they get. If they get the latest version, isn't it misleading to show `-01` in `package.json`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade),

> **yarn upgrade**
>
> This command updates all dependencies to their latest version based on
> the version range specified in the package.json file. The yarn.lock
> file will be recreated as well.

The tricky part is **based on the version range specified in the package.json**

This means that if your `package.json` has defined a particular semver like you've said, `upgrade` will only upgrade it according to the range defined there, i.e. `^1.0-01` **should** upgrade to `1.0-02` in both your `package.json` and `yarn.lock` files.

Now you've said that this is happening only in your `yarn.lock` file. Yarn provides a utility for checking for such clashes called `check`

Could you try running

```
yarn check
```

in your repository and tell us your findings?

Comment: I am still confused about ```yarn upgrade```. According to example given on documentation page https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade, ```yarn upgrade d3-scale``` upgrades ```d3-scales``` from ```^0.9.3``` to ```^1.0.3```. But shouldn't caret ```^``` limit the upgrade range to ```0.*```??

Comment: No worries, I understand it now. Documentation says ```yarn upgrade``` adheres to versioning range given in package.json but ```yarn upgrade package-name``` will update to latest package in npm repository, even across major version.